# Remove "Knowledge base" from subtask view in Jira Service Management Cloud

Tags: jira

I am using Jira Service Management Cloud.

I am trying to remove the "Knowledge base" from subtask view. The problem that "Knowledge base" is nor a custom field nor a system a field. So it doesn't appear on screens or in Field Configuration.

I tried to remove the "Knowledge base" from the screen of subtask, but the field doesn't exist.
Also, I tried to remove it from the layout, but the subtask doesn't have a layout.

How can I remove it for only the subtask view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Knowledge base** is a system field which gets added dynamically to all the issue types when you link a confluence space under Knowledge base settings.

So, you can remove this field by unlinking the spaces in the Knowledge base configuration. However, This will remove the it for all the projects.

Also, you can remove the "Knowledge base" by navigating to a request type > Issue view. But you should have a specific request type configuration for the subtask.